# Accept Insertion and reject deletion openxml

Tags: openxml, openxml-powertools

I need to compare two Word files and merge all insertions into a third one.
I have managed to do that with OpenXML-Power-Tools and WmlCompare, but how do I reject only deletions?

Accepting insertions is easy with `OpenXmlPowerTools.RevisionAccepter` but I can't get the rejection of deletions to work, that way I would get merged file without revisions.

Should I take this approach or would you suggest different approach?

Rules are:

- 1) Text can be added anywhere in the file.
- 2) Text is always added to file, never deleted.
- 3) Files have a .docx file extension

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is relatively easy to reject, or undo, deletions. So, say you have the following sample paragraph with one `w:del` element that wraps a deleted `w:r` element.

```xml
<w:p>
  <w:r>
    <w:t xml:space="preserve">This is </w:t>
  </w:r>
  <w:del w:id="0" w:author="Thomas Barnekow" w:date="2020-02-16T14:37:00Z">
    <w:r>
      <w:delText xml:space="preserve">deleted </w:delText>
    </w:r>
  </w:del>
  <w:r>
    <w:t>text.</w:t>
  </w:r>
</w:p>
```

To reject the deletion, you need to unwrap the deleted `w:r` and turn the `w:delText` into a `w:t` again. Without any further processing (see below), the result of your rejecting the deletion would look like this:

```xml
<w:p>
  <w:r>
    <w:t xml:space="preserve">This is </w:t>
  </w:r>
  <w:r>
    <w:t xml:space="preserve">deleted </w:delText>
  </w:r>
  <w:r>
    <w:t>text.</w:t>
  </w:r>
</w:p>
```

As an optional step, using the `MarkupSimplifier` of the Open XML PowerTools, you could also coalesce adjacent runs having identical formatting, which would result in the following markup:

```xml
<w:p>
  <w:r>
    <w:t>This is deleted text.</w:t>
  </w:r>
</w:p>
```

Comment: Aha, I'll give it a try and I'll let you know.
Thank you.